# double controller value in URL call by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I got a strange problem. while i run my VS and click specific button on browser, an ajax function fired and shows error. After debugging i found the URL is showing error. the error is::
`POST http://localhost:4942/Employee/Employee/AllEmployees 404 (Not Found)`

The problem is, for some reason the "/Employee" controller is coming two times.

my ajax call is:

```
function allEmployeeFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Employee/AllEmployees",
        //data: "{}", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        // context:"" ,   
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("something is wrong");
        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here the URL clearly showing only one /Employee. so whats the problem?? can anyone help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using too much in url; I can see "/Employee/Employee/AllEmployees". Employee twice. Rather try

```
url: "AllEmployees"
```

I guess that should do. Assuming that you have annotation [HttpPost] in place to hit AllEmployees function.

Comment: This solution would work only if you are viewing an action from Employee controller, if you are in a different view from different controller this would not work. You better include controller name in order to access this action from anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a slash to the URL

```
url: "/Employee/AllEmployees"
```

Comment: its not allowing me before 7 min mate.

Comment: You better include controller name in order to access this action from anywhere in the application. If you use the action name only and you try to access this action while viewing another view (for example you are in /Company/AllCompanies) then the action name will be bind to the Company controller which is wrong.